# Angularjs: open on focus and month picker feature to calendar?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I add open on focus feature(similar as Microsoft windows 7 calendar) to my calendar as given in [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ToRNlH6CVLGfk6HOBpCj?p=preview) where we using angular material version1.0.1, please help me with solution.

```
Thanks In advance.
```

Comment: Can you update to Angular Material 1.1.1? If so you can add the `md-open-on-focus` directive to your datepicker.

Comment: Thanks for response, how can i do it without updating Angular material 1.1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to add a custom directive in that case:

```js
.directive('openOnFocus', function () {

  function compile(tElement) {
    tElement.find('input').attr('ng-focus', 'ctrl.onFocus($event)');

    return function (scope, element, attrs, datePicker) {
      var focused = false;

      datePicker.onFocus = (event) => {
        focused = !focused;

        if(focused) {
          datePicker.openCalendarPane(event);
        }
      };
    };
  }

  return {
    compile: compile,
    priority: -1,
    require: 'mdDatepicker',
    restrict: 'A'
  };
});
```

And then:

`<md-datepicker open-on-focus></md-datepicker>`

Taken from this github comment:

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4650#issuecomment-191930096

Comment: Thanks for trying it can you please point the working example of it. Its not working as expected demo(http://plnkr.co/edit/dbR7K1bngMaF7iO4S09o?p=preview).. the calendar icon has to be clickable 1.1.1((material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepick‌​er) ) version calendar is clickable when we click on the (Dec 2016) it give months of year and soon.. but your demo doesn't?

Comment: The calendar in your link looks like it's opening when you click the calendar icon? Not sure what the issue is

Comment: added new question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250474/how-to-extend-datepicker-directive-with-monthpicker-in-calendar-pane please take a look