# How to extend datepicker directive with monthpicker in calendar pane?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angularjs, how can I extend `md-datepicker` directive to implement clickable calendar pane which gives month picker based on selected [month-year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJQ5p.png) it results as [months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa6sF.png). I know that we can archive this in angular material version1.1.1, but we are using angular material version1.0.1.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.1/angular-material.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <md-content>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="birthdate" placeholder="Enter date" md-max-date="maxDate" ></md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.1/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.birthdate = new Date();

    $scope.maxDate = new Date(
      $scope.birthdate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.birthdate.getMonth(),
      $scope.birthdate.getDate());

    $scope.open = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.birthdate = new Date();
        $scope.maxDate = new Date(
          $scope.birthdate.getFullYear(),
          $scope.birthdate.getMonth(),
          $scope.birthdate.getDate());
      }, 400);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use a feature that's only available in 1.1.1 while using a previous version. You'll either have to backport the new feature yourself or update to the newer version. I don't expect there's any other easy fix available.

Comment: you are right, can you please help with the code snippet  which provide the calendar pane which provide month picker from the below files https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.js , https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.css  to back-port my datepicker directive